# Get a variable from a subprocess in python

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess, popen

I have a process running in background as I called it with `subprocess.call("python blabla.py", shell=True)` and I want to get just One variable from it. This variable is the output of a proximity sensor and it has been set to take a measurement every second. I have to take this variable and send it every second to an Android device via Bluetooth. As already said the problem is to isolate this variable inside the main program and use it in there but I don't understand how to properly use Popen or PIPE for this.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you calling a python script subprocess from another python script?

Comment: Because I want to use the variable in the Bluetooth connection script to send it via bluetooth

Comment: The client process must echo the measurement every second. The controller must read it. Look at the examples in subprocess, post code, and someone'll help you.

Comment: I understand that... but why can't you import that `blabla.py` file into your current script, start a thread for whatever it needs to do, then send off your variable from there? Then you bypass the current issue of reading a variables from a `subprocess` call

Comment: @cricket_007 that's because I don't know really how to program in Python as I have to do it for a university project and I am a Mechanical Engineer. However in a way or another I have to do it, and I'll try to see if the method you just told me it's doable for me in low time. If you wanna help me even more it is absolutely appreciated!

Comment: In order to be of any help, I would need you to include a [mcve] of your problem with an [edit] to the question